# add php function to json array before encoding

Tags: php, json

```
$selected_offer = $_POST['selected_offer'];
    $get_categories = $db->query("SELECT oc_id, oc_name FROM object_category WHERE oc_relate = '".$selected_offer."'");

    $json = array();    
    while ($get_rows = mysql_fetch_array($get_categories, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $json[] = $get_rows;
    }

    echo json_encode($json);
    return;
```

I toke this code from someone else and since I am not familiar with json I am asking here at stackoverflow how can add a function to the oc_name attribute before the json encodes it and still return the same struckture as it is now, like for example:

**language($get_rows['oc_name'])**

Comment: why not just echo `json_encode($get_rows);` do the looping after.

Comment: I do the looping with jquery and I cant add php function there

Comment: $get_rows is a fetch array shouldn't it be holding an array of rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while ($get_rows = mysql_fetch_array($get_categories, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $get_rows['oc_name'] = language($get_rows['oc_name']);
    $json[] = $get_rows;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply your function on the mentioned field before you add the row in your `$json` array

```
$json = array();    
while ($get_rows = mysql_fetch_array($get_categories, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $get_rows['oc_name']=language($get_rows['oc_name']);
    $json[] = $get_rows;
}
```